# Why is the parent class abstract when doing inheritance in EF?

Tags: entity-framework

In almost all EF methods that use inheritance, I see that the parent class is marked as `abstract`. Is there any reason why this is done? Or is it just so the abstract class cannot be instantiated?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not mandatory, your base class could not be `abstract`, but as you already said it's  the most common. It's like a inheritance by generalization, which is extracting shared characteristics from two or more classes, and combining them into a generalized superclass, that's why is common see the base class as `abstract`.

In EF there are three different approaches to representing an inheritance hierarchy:

- [**Table per Hierarchy (TPH)**](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-1-table-per-hierarchy-tph): Enable polymorphism by denormalizing the
  SQL schema, and utilize a type discriminator column that holds type
  information.
- [**Table per Type (TPT)**](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt): Represent "is a" (inheritance) relationships as
  "has a" (foreign key) relationships.
- [**Table per Concrete class (TPC)**](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-3-table-per-concrete-type-tpc-and-choosing-strategy-guidelines): Discard polymorphism and inheritance
  relationships completely from the SQL schema.

In the last approach if the base class was concrete, then an additional table would be needed to hold instances of that class.

In summary, if the base class is `abstract` or not depends more on your side if that make sense or not in the model you are trying to represent.

Answer (score 0):

I'd assume because the methods you override are also abstract? Can't have an abstract method on a non-abstract class.
So, for example, it never makes sense to instantiate a plain old DbContext -- you always need collection properties and such. The base DbContext provides functionality which all DbContext derivatives would need (connecting to a database, etc), but isn't useful as a stand-alone object.

Comment: Even if you're overriding virtual methods, the argument stands: a DbContext without collection properties isn't very useful. Marking it abstract avoids any confusion on the matter.